# Dexguard usage obfuscates Android schema in Attributeset

Tags: android, xml, dexguard

I have an Android project where I need to extract the android:textStyle values on TextView creation. I do this by calling the following on the AttributeSet:

```
attrs.getAttributeIntValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android", "textStyle", 0);
```

This gives me the correct textStyle values, set in xml, while I am not using Dexguard. As soon as I obfuscate the code this code piece will always return the default value 0.

I have yet to find a concrete explanation, or reasoning, that might explain why this is happening. So any and all reasonable answers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out Dexguard does obfuscate XML attribute names, and thus referencing 'textStyle' wasn't working.

By adding the following to the rule set this stopped being a problem

```
-keepresourcexmlattributenames **/textStyle
```

This could also be used with replacing the wilcards (**) with the proper XML hierarchy path.